# Code for google/yahoo finance

Tags: feature-request

Oftentimes, I find myself writing a stock ticker or seeing a post that could use one, but I always feel lame writing (ticker: XYZ) or (stock: ABC) and it doesn't seem worth it to go search for a ticker when it's just an example. Could we add a tag like `S:LNKD` that would make a hyperlink to the LinkedIn ticker. I think it would be a pretty useful addition to the site since real examples are always nice, and it would save posters a bit of trouble :)

Comment: Since specific buy/sell advice is off-topic, under what circumstances is a link to a specific ticker appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

As I see it, linking to a ticker would be too localized in time.  If you want to provide a real example, then an image of the pertinent graph or quoting the desired information in the question/answer is the best approach.  That information remains with the question/answer and does not change.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a great idea, and would be very convenient. However, I never have seen any investment website offer something like this e.g. Seeking Alpha, and I think I know why. Implementing what you are describing might require more than just a redirect to Google or Yahoo Finance.

- I know that CUSIPs and SEDOLs (both are security identifiers) are actually licensed products. I'm not sure about stock ticker symbols.
- There are many security types, and they change a lot. Even stock tickers change a lot, with splits, different classes etc. It would be a major maintenance project for Stack Exchange to maintain.

To confirm though, maybe this should be presented to the meta-StackOverflow folks for confirmation? Because it would be great to have if feasible, and would have a lot of appeal to potential users of this site.